# How can I make custom SQL with order by in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My code is here Sql Query :

```
$sql ="select * from products where status='1' AND country='5' AND product_price > "50" AND product_price <= "100" order by product_id desc";
$product=$this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
```

view all products by using customs SQL but still not showing order by desc.

Comment: Please post your table structure and data with expected output of query.

Comment: I have no problems expected output of query but problems is don't showing desc order.

Comment: try this, select * from products where status='1' AND country='5' AND product_price > '50' AND product_price <= '100' order by product_id desc

Comment: select * from products where status='1' AND country='5' AND product_price > '50' AND product_price <= '100' order by product_id desc still not showing.

Comment: Can you post the result of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `status`=1 AND `country`=5 AND `product_price` > 50 AND `product_price` <= 100 ORDER BY `product_id` DESC";
        $product = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use built-in Codeigniter Query-builder:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where([
    'status'    => 1,
    'country'   => 5,
    'product_price >' => 50,
    'product_price <=' => 100,
]);
$this->db->order_by('product_id', 'DESC');
$this->db->get('products');
$product = $this->db->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

```
$query = $this->db->query('select * from products where status='1' AND country='5' AND product_price > "50" AND product_price <= "100" order by product_id desc');
$row_array = $query->result_array();
```

I Hop it will help you.

Comment: Ok, I will check.

Comment: Don't work! this query, in fact, this query same as my query.

Comment: Please post your table structure with datatype of each field

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->from('products');
$this->db->where("status='1' AND country='5' AND product_price > '50' AND product_price <= '100'", null, false);
$this->db->order_by("product_id", "desc");
$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: I want to custom query.I don't use active records query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
$this->db->select('products.*');
$this->db->from('products');
$sql="status='1' AND country='5' AND (product_price > '50' AND product_price <= '100')";
$this->db->where($sql, NULL, FALSE)->order_by("product_id", "DESC");

$products_query = $this->db->get();

$products_info_array = array();

$products_info_array = $products_query->result_array();

return $products_info_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you "describe" type the table? If the field "product_id" is text (Example: **VARCHAR**), then it will never follow the order asc/desc..

Sorry My English.. **Good work**!

Comment: product_id field is "int(11), AUTO_INCREMENT and primary key"